# Why didDiscoverPeripheral is not calling

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have initialise object.

```
centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: bt_queue)
```

then delegate method called

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)
```

in that method I have called

```
centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
```

but my `didDiscover peripheral:`  not called any reason ?

using iOS 11.2.5 and x-code 9.2

Comment: Are you doing it in background?

Comment: @AgentSmith no.

Comment: Could you put the whole code of your `didDiscoverPeripheral`. Also, are you sure that the second device you are looking for is BLE and advertising? Did you try with LightBlue.app if you are able to see it?

Comment: @Larme I am checking with other iPhone's bluetooth.

Comment: No. Try with LightBlue.app. Also, I pointed out this: "are you sure that the second device you are looking for is BLE and advertising", importants part being "BLE and Advertising". My iPhone is BLE (chip BLE), but it's not advertising in BLE unless I tell him to do so.

Comment: @Larme great. iPhone's bluetooth is not discoverable but bluetooth speaker is discoverable. I think because iPhone using classic BT and BT speaker using BLE.

Comment: No. iPhone is BLE compatible (>= iPhone 4S). But you have to develop/use an app that it make the BLE Stack and advertise, if not, your iPhone won't do it by itself.

Comment: @Larme ok. if my iPhone is advertising or work as Peripheral than it is discoverable.